# Find distribution and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Random variable X has the density specified by the formula:

$$
y = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
x+1 & \textrm{ $ x\in <-1,0)$}\\
1-x & \textrm{ $x \in <0, 1)$}\\
0 & \textrm{for the rest of x}
\end{array} \right.
$$

a) Find the distributor $F(x)$

b) Find $x_0$ that $P(X \ge x_0) = \frac{7}{8}$

Could you help me the most with b)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\mathbb P(X \ge x_0) = 1 - \mathbb P(X \le x_0) = 1 - F(x_0)$

Once you find $F(x)$, you should be able to solve $x_0$.

Comment: $$F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x \leqslant -1\\
\int_1^x t\operatorname d t & \; -1 < x <0\\
\int_{-1}^0 t+1\operatorname d t+\int_0^x 1-t \operatorname d t & 0 \leqslant x < 1\\
1 & 1\leqslant x
\end{cases}$$
How to find the best $x_0$ ?

Comment: @json (1) You have the second case incorrect (typo?) (2) Evaluate the integrals. (3) Examine $F(0)$  What does that tell you about the placement of $x_0$ in the support if $F(x_0)=1/8$ . (4) Solve for $x_0$.

Comment: @json, could you show me what is the $F(x)$ that you solve?